# Resetting php memory limit after increasing it?

Tags: php

So I have some legacy code thats going over the allotted memory, it would be a nightmare to try and figure out why and how to fix it. So I know you can do the dreaded: `ini_set("memory_limit", "2048M");` but is there a way to then, after said code executes, reset the memory limit back to what it was?

Comment: don't think so, once the program starts running the memory is allocated.  once the program ends, it releases the memory

Comment: use something like  `$limit = ini_get('memory_limit')` then set it again with the old value `ini_set("memory_limit", $limit)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this (although I never tried it with memory limit)

```
//get the current limit
$memlimit = ini_get('memory_limit');
//set it to something else
ini_set("memory_limit", "2048M");

//... do some stuff

//set it back
ini_set("memory_limit", $memlimit);
```

I've used this for error reporting and a few other things (don't ask).  So it might work :-/

I should also explain (just in case you don't know) setting anything with `ini_set` only affects the currently running PHP instance, so outside of that instance (request) everything will be what is in the `php.ini` file.

For reference  (even thought it's pretty self explanatory)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php

> ini_get — Gets the value of a configuration option

Yea so it's just a matter of getting the value, assigning it to a variable for storage, doing your thing, then setting it back to what it was.